# Как переформатировать номер телефона из +79999999999 в 8 (999) 999-99-99?

Tags: jquery

имеется скрипт, который вставляет телефон в атрибут href в формате +79999999999, как сделать чтобы в текстовую часть вставлялся переформатированный номер в формате 8 (999) 999-99-99?

```
window.onload = function() {        
    var phone = jQuery('.ose-form .ose-form-phone-block .ose-link').text();
    jQuery('.site-header-top-left .kl-header-toptext a').text(phone);
    jQuery('.site-header-top-left .kl-header-toptext a').attr('href', 'tel:' + phone);
};
```

Comment: При чём тут jquery?  Надо просто regexp

Comment: [https://webstool.ru/jquery.maskedinput.html](https://webstool.ru/jquery.maskedinput.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой вариант с ходу, так сказать.

```js
const NumReg = new RegExp(/(\d{1,3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})/);
const NumTmp = '$1 ($2) $3-$4-$5';

function FormatNumber(num) {
  let format = num.replace(NumReg, NumTmp);
  
  return format.replace(/^\+7/, '8');
}

console.log(FormatNumber('+79999999999'));
console.log(FormatNumber('89123456789'));
console.log(FormatNumber('+3809123456789')); // UA
```